# How to stop lines of an algorithm from jumping up and down

Tags: beamer, algorithms, highlighting

I have the following code to walk though the lines of an algorithm:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}
\def\HiLi{\leavevmode\rlap{\hbox to \hsize{\color{yellow!50}\leaders\hrule height .8\baselineskip depth .5ex\hfill}}}
\title{Beamer Template}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{}
    Some text...
    
    \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{\textheight}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{minipage}[H]{.85\textwidth}
                \begin{algorithm}[H]
                    \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
                    \only<1>{\HiLi}\Input{$G$, $W$}
                    \only<2>{\HiLi}$Q \leftarrow V$\;
                    \only<3>{\HiLi}$key[v] \leftarrow \infty$ for all $v \in V$\;
                    \only<4>{\HiLi}$key[s] \leftarrow 0$ for some arbitrary $s \in V$\;
                    \only<5>{\HiLi}\While{$Q \neq \emptyset$} {
                        \only<6>{\HiLi}$u \leftarrow ${\sc Extract-Min}$(Q)$\;
                        \only<7>{\HiLi}\For{each node $v$ in Adj$[u]$}{
                            \only<8>{\HiLi}\If{$v \in Q$ and $w(u,v) < key[v]$} {
                                \only<9>{\HiLi}$key[v] \leftarrow w(u,v)$  // {\sc Decrease-Key}\;
                                \only<10>{\HiLi}$\pi[v] \leftarrow u$\;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                \end{algorithm}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{center}
    \end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

As the highlighting moves down the lines the line being highlighted moves. I tried increasing the spacing between lines with \setspace but that didn't help. How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the highlighted area is too high and too deep. By trial and error, I have found values that fix this problem.

```
\def\HiLi{\leavevmode\rlap{\hbox to \hsize{\color{yellow!50}\leaders\hrule height .55\baselineskip depth .4ex\hfill}}}
```

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}
\def\HiLi{\leavevmode\rlap{\hbox to \hsize{\color{yellow!50}\leaders\hrule height .55\baselineskip depth .4ex\hfill}}}
\title{Beamer Template}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{}
    Some text...

    \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{\textheight}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{minipage}[H]{.85\textwidth}
                \begin{algorithm}[H]
                    \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
                    \only<1>{\HiLi}\Input{$G$, $W$}
                    \only<2>{\HiLi}$Q \leftarrow V$\;
                    \only<3>{\HiLi}$key[v] \leftarrow \infty$ for all $v \in V$\;
                    \only<4>{\HiLi}$key[s] \leftarrow 0$ for some arbitrary $s \in V$\;
                    \only<5>{\HiLi}\While{$Q \neq \emptyset$} {
                        \only<6>{\HiLi}$u \leftarrow ${\sc Extract-Min}$(Q)$\;
                        \only<7>{\HiLi}\For{each node $v$ in Adj$[u]$}{
                            \only<8>{\HiLi}\If{$v \in Q$ and $w(u,v) < key[v]$} {
                                \only<9>{\HiLi}$key[v] \leftarrow w(u,v)$  // {\sc Decrease-Key}\;
                                \only<10>{\HiLi}$\pi[v] \leftarrow u$\;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                \end{algorithm}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{center}
    \end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.